# How can I to add upload functionality outside of the admin area?

Tags: posts, uploads

I am looking into updating this template (http://templatic.com/demos/answers/?ptype=ask-a-question) which allows logged in subscribers to post (questions). I would like to add an option to upload a file and attach it to the post.

I was thinking of using the media-upload functionality, but I do not want to give users full access to the media library.

How could this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't find much on the Codex or the net about this. Media can seem like a pretty dark art, but everything you're looking for is in [/wp-admin/includes/media.php](http://svn.automattic.com/wordpress/tags/3.1/wp-admin/includes/media.php).

The function you're looking for is `media_handle_sideload()`. You'll have to pass it a `$file_array`, which you'll have to read up on.

Basically you just make sure your file information is all up to snuff, pass it into this function and it creates something that acts a lot like a regular post and can be manipulated via the media tools and [custom post querie](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query)s with `post_type=attachment` argument.

Comment: aha! thank you! A dark art makes it sound intriguing.

Comment: NOTE: Did you mean **[wp-admin/includes/media.php](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1/wp-admin/includes/media.php)** and not **wp-includes/media.php**?